# Python - dict full of identical values

Tags: python, list, dictionary, multiple-entries

Really can't get out of this...
Here's my python code:

```
 for i in range(len(realjson)) : 
    store["Store"]={
          "id"          :realjson[i]['id'].strip(),
          "retailer_id" :RETAILER_ID,
          "name"        :find(realjson[i]["title"],">","<").strip(),
          "address"     :realjson[i]["address"].strip(),
          "city"        :realjson[i]["address"].split(",")[-4].strip(),
          "province"    :realjson[i]["address"].split(",")[-3].strip(),
          "group"       :realjson[i]["address"].split(",")[-1].strip(),
          "zip"         :realjson[i]["address"].split(",")[-2].strip(),
          "url"         :"http://blabla.com?id="+realjson[i]["id"].strip(),
          "lat"         :realjson[i]["lat"].strip(),
          "lng"         :realjson[i]["lon"].strip(),
          "phone"       :realjson[i]["telephone_number"].replace("<br />Phone Number: ","").strip()
          }

    stores.append(store)
    print stores[i]
```

When I print the list inside the for loop it works correctly.
Otherwise when I print the array outside the loop like this:
`print stores`it contains only the last element that I've appended repeated for the entire length of the list.
Do you have some advice to help me!
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You reuse a mutable object in your loop:

```
store['Store']
```

Create a new copy in the loop instead:

```
newstore = store.copy()
newstore['Store'] = { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
store["Store"]={ ... }
```

if you expect this line to create new dictionary with just one key, then what you actually want is

```
store = {"Store": { ... }}
```